# Pinning a fixed array of strings and getting char* for each index

Tags: c#, pointers, unsafe

I have to pass a pointer of type char* to a structure in C# and I can successfully do it with this code:

```
  string myText = "Hello World";
  fixed (char* ptrText = myText) {
    lvItem.pszText = ptrText;
    ....
  }
```

However, I have to do this 20 times, and I would like to avoid pinning/fixing all 20 strings in a loop and instead populate them in an array of strings and just pin that array (seems more efficient), but I cannot get the part of pinning the whole array and then getting the address of each element as a char* pointer.

```
  string[] arrStrings = new string[20];
  fixed (string* ptrArray = arrStrings) {
     lvItem.pszText = &ptrArray[1]    // this doesn't work
     ....
  }
```

Anyone knows how is this done in unsafe context in C#?

Comment: String is a reference type, you must pin them individually. And today you should use `ReadOnlySpan<char>` more often.

Comment: How does a ReadOnlySpan benefits me here? I still need it to be pinned and get the address of it, right? care to explain further?

Comment: That's just a suggestion, but AFAIK there should be no need to pin a string, you can read: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/default-marshalling-for-strings

Comment: Why do you need to do this? If you are doing PInvoke then the marshaller is perfectly capable of doing all this automatically if you just pass an array of `string[]`. What are you *actually* trying to achieve?

Comment: @Charlieface  I can use the Marshaller and define the field on the structure as [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)]  char* pszText; and that will take care of itself, However, that only works If I use the DllImport function, not with the new LibraryImport one, it cannot take a field in that way.

I am trying to SendMessage to a ListView passing a pointer to a string on the structure to set the text of an item.

Comment: That's because it doesn't support Auto charset. You can specify The Ansi version `LPStr` explicitly. https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/docs/design/libraries/LibraryImportGenerator/Compatibility.md#string-marshalling Or create `byte[]` arrays like `lvItem.pszText = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(YourString);` Having said that, I'm going to hazard a guess that you're creating a `LVITEMA` struct, you can use the Wide/Unicode versions of the messages `LVM_GETITEMW` etc and pass UTF-16 instead.

Comment: @Charlieface I see, I am actually using the W version, Unicode, So I should have wrote LPWStr. My bad... However, I am a bit lost on how I should declare the struct part and the LibraryImport part to not need to pin/fix the string variable in first place. Do you mind illustrating?
For example, with the regular DllImport P/Invoke declaration, I can just write the struct as [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] internal string pszText; and it will work, but I cannot get the same with LibraryImport , I actually dont care if its ansi, utf8 or 16, its just plain regular text.

Comment: Seems that `LibraryImport` requires a `CustomMarshaller` for structs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/native-interop/tutorial-custom-marshaller